Compute the "tricky" line integral using generalized Stokes theorem
We want to compute this line integral over the 2-torus $S^1 \times S^1$ with respect to the product orientation
$$\int_{S^1 \times S^1} \left( zw + e^x \sin(y) \right) \, dx \wedge dy + \left( e^{y+z} - 2xw \right) \, dy \wedge dz$$
Hint: $S^1 \times S^1$ is the boundary of a solid 3-dimensional torus given by $D^2 \times S^1$.
$\mathbb{Proof:}$ We use the general Stokes theorem. First, we compute the exterior derivative and then apply Stokes theorem using the hint in the problem.
Let $\alpha = \left( zw + e^x \sin(y) \right) \, dx \wedge dy + \left( e^{y+z} - 2xw \right) \, dy \wedge dz$ be the 2-form over the torus in $\mathbb{R^2}$ $\times$ $\mathbb{R^2}$ = $\mathbb{R^4}$.
$$d\alpha = d\left( \left( zw + e^x \sin(y) \right) \, dx \wedge dy \right) + d\left( \left( e^{y+z} - 2xw \right) \, dy \wedge dz \right)$$ is the exterior derivative which is a $3$ form.
For the first term of the exterior derivative, we have:
$$d\left( \left( zw + e^x \sin(y) \right) \, dx \wedge dy \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left( zw + e^x \sin(y) \right) \, dz \wedge dx \wedge dy + \frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left( zw + e^x \sin(y) \right) \, dw \wedge dx \wedge dy$$
And, by simplifying, we get: $$d\left( zw + e^x \sin(y) \right) = w \, dz + z \, dw$$
So, we have: $$d\left( zw + e^x \sin(y) \right) \, dx \wedge dy = w \, dz \wedge dx \wedge dy + z \, dw \wedge dx \wedge dy$$
For the second term of the exterior derivative above:
$$d\left( \left( e^{y+z} - 2xw \right) \, dy \wedge dz \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( e^{y+z} - 2xw \right) \, dx \wedge dy \wedge dz + \frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left( e^{y+z} - 2xw \right) \, dw \wedge dy \wedge dz$$
And, by simplifying, $$    d\left( e^{y+z} - 2xw \right) = -2w \, dx + e^{y+z} \,dz
$$. Thus, we have:
$$d\left( e^{y+z} - 2xw \right) \, dy \wedge dz = -2w \ dx \wedge dy \wedge dz + e^{y+z} \ dw \wedge dy \wedge dz.$$
Now, combining both terms together and simplifying further,
$$d\alpha = \left( w \, dz \wedge dx \wedge dy + z \, dw \wedge dx \wedge dy \right) + \left( -2w \, dx \wedge dy \wedge dz + e^{y+z} \, dw \wedge dy \wedge dz \right)$$
$$d\alpha = \left( z \, dw \wedge dx \wedge dy + e^{y+z} \, dw \wedge dy \wedge dz \right)$$
Now, we can use the hint given in the problem: We integrate the 3-form $d\alpha$ over $D^2 \times S^1$ using the generalized Stokes theorem.
I do not know how to finish the last part of the problem for some reason. Thank you

Are you sure $S^1\times S^1$ is supposed to be sitting in $\mathbb R^4$ and not $\mathbb R^3$?

Also your calculation is incorrect

Where is it wrong? The problem states that it is a subset of $R^2 \times R^2$

Your second calculation. $e^{y+z}$ should go to zero. Also, I am not getting zero when I do this integral either though. I am getting something like $-2\pi^2$.

@Chris the space over which we are integrating the line integral is the torus -  the product of two unit circles. The problem says that it is a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ $\times$ $\mathbb{R^2}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^4}$. However, I do not think that it is really important for the computation. It is a differential $2$-form, so I computed the exterior derivative (I am a bit rusty on that to be fair) and then applied Stokes using the hint. In the end, I did not get zero. My intuition is that the exterior derivative is a 3-form over the torus and it should result in zero by symmetry.

it matters because I was wondering whether $w$ was a coordinate or a constant. This doesn't change the fact that your exterior derivative calculation is incorrect. \begin{align}
d(e^{y+z}-2xw)\wedge dy\wedge dz=&(e^{y+z}dy+e^{y+z}dz-2xdw-2wdx)\wedge dy \wedge dz\
=&0+0-2xdw\wedge dy\wedge dz-2wdx\wedge dy \wedge dz
\end{align}

When integradint this form over $D^2\times S^1$, you can replace $(x,y)$ with $(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$, and $(w,z)$ with $(\cos\phi,\sin \phi)$. In these coordinates (I think, could have messed up the calculation) you get the three form $-r^2dr\wedge d\theta\wedge d\phi$, which I don't think integrates to zero.

Ah, sorry! Thanks for pointing this out. The coordinates are $(x,y,z, w) = ((x,y),(z,w))$ on $\mathbb{R^4}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$ $\times $ $\mathbb{R^2}$. So, that $\omega$ I denoted is the integrand so this is really a bad choice of notation which messes things up a lot.

I updated it to proper notation.

your calculation of the exterior derivative is still incorrect though. In particular, you should have no exponential term

In the first one or the second one? Do you mind sharing your computation? You said you did not get zero.

Perhaps you might find some of my YouTube videos helpful, e.g., this one and the following one, where I specifically address the torus in $\Bbb R^4$.

@TedShifrin I watched it the first one and it is useful. If you have a chance, can you verify if Chris's proof is correct. I am pretty sure it is correct though computing the exterior derivative is tricky sometimes.

Perhaps you should ask a separate question about this, but I don't think of computing exterior derivatives as tricky at all. To differentiate $\omega=f dx_I$ (with $I$ a multi-index), you get $df\wedge dx_I$, and because $dx_i\wedge dx_i=0$, only the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to the indices not appearing in $I$ will contribute. Thus, we get $d\omega=\sum_{j\notin I} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} dx_j\wedge dx_I$. Then you can reorder terms (with appropriate signs) as you wish. On the other hand, orientations and boundary orientations sometimes require some serious thought. :)

I'll post my calculation so that there is more space, though I may have have messed up somewhere.
Let:
$$\omega= (zw+e^x\sin y)dx\wedge dy+( e^{y+z} - 2xw )  dy \wedge dz$$
We first calculate $d\omega$. The first term has $dx\wedge dy$, so the only nonzero terms are derivatives of $z$ and $w$. The second only has $x$ and $w$, hence:
\begin{align}
d\omega=&z dw\wedge dx\wedge dy+w dz\wedge dx \wedge dy-2wdx\wedge dy\wedge dz-2xdw\wedge dy \wedge dz\\
=&z dx \wedge dy\wedge dw-wdx\wedge dy \wedge dz+2xdy\wedge dw\wedge dz
\end{align}
We have that $(x,y)=(r\cos \theta,r\sin \theta)$, and $(z,w)=(\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$, so with this in mind we calculate that:
\begin{align}
d\omega=&-r\cos \phi\sin \phi dr\wedge d\theta\wedge d\phi+r\sin^2\phi dr\wedge d\theta\wedge d\phi\\
=&rdr\wedge d\theta\wedge d\phi
\end{align}
A quick way of seeing the above change of coordinates calculation is to note that the third term has the component $dw\wedge dz=d(\cos\phi)\wedge d(\sin\phi)=g(\phi)d\phi\wedge d\phi=0$ for some $g(\phi)$. For the other two terms note that $dx\wedge dy=d(r\cos\theta)\wedge d(r\sin\theta)=rdr\wedge d\theta$.
The integral of $\int_{D^2\times S^1}d\omega$ is then given by:
\begin{align}
\int_{D^2\times S^1}d\omega=&\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1rdrd\theta d\phi\\
=&4\pi^2\int_0^1rdr\\
=&2\pi^2
\end{align}
This matches with the direct integral of $\omega$ over $S^1\times S^1$. Indeed, we can switch to coordinates $(x,y)=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$ and $(z,w)=(\cos\phi,\sin \phi)$. The first term in $\omega$ becomes zero because $d\cos\theta\wedge d\sin\theta=0$. It follows that:
\begin{align}
\omega=&(e^{\sin\theta+\cos \phi}-2\cos\theta\sin\phi)(d\sin\theta)\wedge (d\cos \phi)\\
=&(-e^{\sin\theta+\cos\phi}\cos\theta\sin\phi+2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi)d\theta\wedge d\phi
\end{align}
so:
\begin{align}
\int_{S^1\times S^1}\omega=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(-e^{\sin\theta+\cos\phi}\cos\theta\sin\phi+2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi)d\theta d\phi
\end{align}
The second term integrates precisely to $2\pi^2$, I will show that the first term integrates to zero.
We have that:
\begin{align}
I=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\sin\theta+\cos\phi}\cos\theta d\theta\right)\sin\phi d\phi
\end{align}
Make the substitution $u=e^{\sin\theta+\cos \phi}$, then $du=e^{\sin\theta+\cos\phi}\cos\theta d\theta$, hence:
\begin{align}
I=&\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}du\right)\sin\phi d\phi\\
=&\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\phi 
 d\phi\right)\left(e^{\sin\theta+\cos\phi}\Big|_{0}^{2\pi}\right)\\
=&0\cdot0
\end{align}
So the integral of $\omega$ over $S^1\times S^1$ is indeed $2\pi^2$.

But we agreed that we use $\alpha$ for the integrand instead of $\omega$. The coordinates are $(x,y)$ and $(z,\omega)$. This does not mess up the computation?

Also, I am a bit confused about why we need to do a change of variable.

For some reason, my computations are pretty long for both terms of the exterior derivative. I just don't feel that I follow your proof.

What you have written is a $2$ form on $\mathbb R^4$ which you are integrating over the submanifold $S^1\times S^1$. Implicitly this is the same as pulling back $\omega$ by the inclusion map $\iota:S^1\times S^1\hookrightarrow \mathbb R^4$ and then integrating. However $d(\iota^\omega)=\iota^(d\omega)$, so it does not matter "where we perform" the exterior derivative. I made the change of variable because this makes the integral easier, by all means though you need not do such a thing.

My question is: Can we use a different letter for the integrand? As it might mess up the coordinates?

@Gradmath what do you mean? your a $\alpha$ is precisely defined as my $\omega$.

using the same letter for the coordinate and integrand can be confusing.

it's not the same letter, one is $w$ a coordinate, the other is $\omega$ a 2 form.

that sounds good! thanks!

perhaps I can wait a day or two to see what other mathematicians think about the proof. Then I will accept it as an answer. I tried it myself and I think this is correct.

@GradMath I realized I did not make an error in the coordinate change sorry.  however, I have updated the answer with a direct calculation of the integral over $S^1\times S^1$ and the answers match.

that sounds great! Do you think I can polish your proof so readers won't be confused by the edits? I mean as a whole proof without "edits". I will also update the last part of my problem so there is less confusion. Thank you so much!

@Gradmath, I have edited the post to polish the answer. Is this more readable for you?

$0 \times 0$ is a bit confusing. I really meant writing as a coherent answer for others to follow through the proof. It seems we do different computations in the answer. Thanks!

@Gradmath if your solution is drastically different from mine, I encourage you to post your own answer.

I also checked the way you computed and it is indeed $2\pi^2$. My comment was all about the organization of the proof. I did not want to mess up your proof by doing it. Thanks for the help, though!

I think there is a typo when you explain that this matches with the original integral. The coordinates $(z,w) = (cos\phi, sin\phi)$?

Thanks for the edit. Also, when you do the u-subsitution in the last edit, is $d\theta$ missing in the derivative? Thanks!

@Gradmath yes it was, everything should be fixed now I believe

thanks! It looks great!
